# compass socket hangup with grunt serve

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compass

I was running grunt-contrib-compass@0.6.0 and it was aborting with this error:

```
node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js:261
  throw err;
        ^
Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (http.js:1476:15)
at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1526:23)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at TCP.close (net.js:465:12)
```

I upgraded to grunt-contrib-compass@1.0.1 and now it no longer exits, but it produces the following errors/warnings  (it no longer exits when this happens, even though it says fatal)

```
Fatal error: socket hang up
Fatal error: socket hang up
```

Which I can only assume is the same problem with better error handling.  Is there some way to get better information out of whatever is throwing this error?  This is the compass portion of my Gruntfile

```
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: 'styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            trace: true
        },
        dist: {},
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug with compass.  I was using the ubuntu distro version of ruby-compass which was having problem, `sudo gem install compass` has ended the problem for now.